# Standardize numeric formats from different regions

Tags: sql-server, validation, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm doing a massive cleanup on an old system and I have a SQL Server database table with a `TEXT`-type column where numeric (including money) data was stored (as well as text data too), often in a localized format or typo'd horribly. I need to standardize the data to American numeric standards.

Examples of some of the data:

```
$1,000 - Good!
$1.000 - Bad, should have been $1,000
$1,000.000 - Bad, should have been $1,000,000
$1,000.000.00 - Bad, should have been $1,000,000.00
$1.000.000,00 - Bad, should have been $1,000,000.00
$10,.000 - Bad, should have been $10,000
500.000 - Bad, should have been 500,000
1.325% - Good!
```

I gave some examples because I wanted to illustrate some of the difficulties in finding and correcting the issues. I'm going under the premise that a period followed by 3 digits should have been a comma (unless it was perhaps a precise % and not a $), but a period followed by 2 digits was correct. Anyone have any suggests for cleaning this up in SQL or an outside-the-box solution that may be better?

Comment: Throw away commas and deal with multiple dots?

Comment: I don't think that would be good enough. We could have something like this: $1.000.000,00 that would make the value change if we just threw out the commas

Comment: well this is stored as a varchar so nothing is going to prevent it from happening again, correct? Why not fix it on the input, or application side? We can code a case statement... but it'll be never ending as possibilities emerge

Comment: If there is a value like `100.500` I don't see any change to decide, whether this is `100500` or `100.5` without some knowledge of the data's source (culture)...

Comment: This is a script to clean it up to prepare to migrate it to a new system. If we try to migrate it right now, things like the $500.000 turn into $500 in the new system. So in this case, we're "fixing" the input by changing systems...lol

Comment: That's why I am making certain assumptions  (like anything with a $ should not have a . followed by more than 2 digits).

Comment: But how do you know that $500.000 should be 500000? And it wasn't a typo for 500.00? There is so much room for mistakes in trying to do what you are doing here. The more code you throw at this the more holes you will find. This is why you should be careful designing your databases. At best you need to use regular expressions which t-sql does not support. Doing this directly in the database is never going to be accurate enough to be more than close. Honestly what needs to happen is a human doing this row by agonizing row.

Comment: I agree (and I would have never designed the database this way). But unfortunately this is what has been handed to me. RBAR is not an option because we have 1.7 million rows of data, so we have to make best-guess assumptions and let the cleanup happen in the new system.

Comment: You could add a nullable column of an appropriate data type, e.g. `DecimalValue as Decimal(16,4)`, with a default of NULL. Start running passes to update the column using `like`, e.g. `update MyTable set DecimalValue = Cast( TextValue as Decimal(16,4) ) where DecimalValue is NULL and TextValue like '$[0-9].[0-9][0-9]';`. Repeat with different patterns and conversion logic until you have converted all of the "reasonable" interpretations. Then look at the remaining NULLs and see what text is salvageable.

Comment: @HABO I like that idea and it's the kind of answer I'm looking for. Just trying to come up with some good ideas for getting an 80% solution (because without divine powers, I could never get a 100% solution)

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my previously posted comment:

For a one-time conversion of existing data into a new format, you can attack the problem in steps:

Add a nullable column to the table with an appropriate numeric data type, e.g. `Decimal(16,4)`, initialized to NULL.

Additional columns may be useful depending on the semantics of the existing data. It may make sense to capture units, e.g. USD or percent, and scale, i.e. the number of places to the right of the radix point.

Start converting the data one step at a time. Short and simple patterns can be dispensed with first, e.g.:

```
-- Process "$n.nn".
update MyTable
  set DecimalValue = Cast( TextValue as Decimal(16,4) ),
    Unit = 'USD', Scale = 2 -- If desired.
  where DecimalValue is NULL and TextValue like '$[0-9].[0-9][0-9]';
```

Tip: Save the statements in a stored procedure or text file so that you can flush the converted data and start over as wisdom accumulates.

More complex data will require additional conversion logic, e.g.:

```
-- Process "$n.nnn,nn".
update MyTable
  set DecimalValue = Cast( Replace( Replace( TextValue, '.', '' ), ',', '.' ) as Decimal(16,4) )
  where DecimalValue is NULL and TextValue like '$[0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9]';
```

Patterns can be combined in a single statement where appropriate:

```
-- Process ".nn%", "n.nn%" and "nn.nn%".
update MyTable
  set DecimalValue = Cast( Replace( TextValue, '%', '' ) as Decimal(16,4) ),
    Unit = 'percent', Scale = 2 -- If desired.
  where DecimalValue is NULL and (
    TextValue like '.[0-9][0-9]*%' escape '*' or
    TextValue like '[0-9].[0-9][0-9]*%' escape '*' or
    TextValue like '[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]*%' escape '*' );
```

As you progress through the conversions you can review the remaining text values, `where DecimalValue is NULL`, to see what patterns make sense, what to convert manually and what data is simply not salvageable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sean and Shnugo, this would get you started but **also** highlight how it could fail so easily. Anything but the types of issues in the sample data could cause issues.

```
declare @table table (ID int identity (1,1), c1 varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('$1,000'), --good
('$1.000'), -- Bad, should have been $1,000
('$1,000.000'), -- Bad, should have been $1,000,000
('$1,000.000.00'), -- Bad, should have been $1,000,000.00
('$10,.000'), -- Bad, should have been $10,000
('500.000'), -- Bad, should have been 500,000
('1.325%'), -- Good!
('1,325%') -- bad!

select
    *,
    case
        when c1 like '%\%%' escape '\' then replace(c1,',','.') --simply replaces commas with periods for % signed values
        else 
            case                                                --simply replaces periods for commans for non % signed values, and takes into account ,00 at the end should be .00
                                                                --also handles double commas, once
                when left(right(replace(replace(c1,'.',','),',,',','),3),1) = ','
                then stuff(replace(replace(c1,'.',','),',,',','),len(replace(replace(c1,'.',','),',,',',')) - 2,1,'.')
                else replace(replace(c1,'.',','),',,',',')      
            end 
    end
from @table
```